# Cannot round up a number

Tags: vbscript, rounding

I have the following code:

```
Dim a as Long
a = InputBox("a=")
Dim nr_cifre as Long
nr_cifre = 0
Dim n as Long
n=a
Do While n <> 0
    n=n / 10
    nr_cifre = nr_cifre + 1
Loop
If a - a mod (10 * nr_cifre) = 0.5 Then
    a=a+0.9+(nr_cifre*10)
End If
MsgBox a mod (10 * nr_cifre)
```

Basically, it tries to round up numbers. So, 2.3 will become 2. Also, it tries to round up, for example, 2.5 to 3.

The example works for small numbers, like 1234,5. But if I try to round up 12345,6, it gives me some weird errors. I have also tried the code in VB6, but without success.

May I ask for your help/suggestions? Any tip is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have something against Round -- `round(2.6,0)`? Admittedly it performs bankers rounding, but that seems to be what you want. See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/26/bankers-rounding.aspx

Comment: "gives me some weird errors" means nothing to anyone but you, because we can't see your screen or read your mind. If you're getting an error, please provide the **exact error** you're getting or problem you're having, including any error messages you receive. (And you can use `Round` (or `Ceiling` if you always want to round up; it may be `Ceil` in VBScript - I don't recall), either of which is better than trying to write your own.)

Comment: @Remou I have to make an algorithm on my own this time, so I cannot use embedded functions from the programming language.

Comment: @Ken White Oh, yes, sorry, for example, for 12345.6 it gives me 2506...

Comment: I also want 0.5 to become 1, not 0 as in Bankers' rounding.

Comment: @KenWhite VBScript doesn't have a `ceil` (or `ceiling`) function. That would be JScript.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Thanks. As I said, I didn't recall. It's been a long time since I had to resort to VBScript to get anything done. :-)

Comment: If this is your exact code, then it isn't VBScript (VBScript doesn't allow you to specify `As Long`). What is the actual language? How are you running the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need your own algorithm then try this:

```
WSH.Echo CustomRound(-123456.7) '-123457
WSH.Echo CustomRound(-123456.5) '-123456
WSH.Echo CustomRound(-123456.3) '-123456
WSH.Echo CustomRound(123456.7)  '123457
WSH.Echo CustomRound(123456.5)  '123457
WSH.Echo CustomRound(123456.3)  '123456

Function CustomRound(nValue)
    CustomRound = Int(nValue + 0.5)
End Function
```

or...

```
WSH.Echo CustomRound2(-123456.7) '-123457
WSH.Echo CustomRound2(-123456.5) '-123457
WSH.Echo CustomRound2(-123456.3) '-123456
WSH.Echo CustomRound2(123456.7)  '123457
WSH.Echo CustomRound2(123456.5)  '123457
WSH.Echo CustomRound2(123456.3)  '123456

Function CustomRound2(nValue)
    CustomRound2 = Sgn(nValue) * Int(Abs(nValue) + 0.5)
End Function
```

Well... one more idea :)

```
Function RoundFrm(nValue)
    RoundFrm = Null
    If IsEmpty(nValue) Or _
    Not IsNumeric(nValue) Then Exit Function
    RoundFrm = FormatNumber(nValue, 0)
End Function
```

And using above idea can make more complete function like...

```
Function RoundEx(nValue)
    Select Case VarType(nValue)
        Case vbInteger, vbLong
            RoundEx = nValue
        Case vbSingle
            RoundEx = CSng(FormatNumber(nValue, 0))
        Case vbDouble
            RoundEx = CDbl(FormatNumber(nValue, 0))
        Case vbCurrency
            RoundEx = CCur(FormatNumber(nValue, 0))
        Case Else: RoundEx = Null
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: I tried something similar above on my code, but instead of the Int function, I did mod which gives the same result. In fact, I think that the error is generated by the digits counting loop...

Comment: I update my answer with one more function. I used both concept in language that has not builtin Round function (only Ceil/Floor), and I think it's proved.